# Question about the analytic continuation of zeta

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

Im reading about the analytic continuation of the zeta function. I'll assume that you know the analytic continuation so I'll write in mainfolds,

We prove that
$ \varGamma\left(s\right)\zeta\left(s\right)=\intop_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^{t}-1}dtm$

And we write $ \intop_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^{t}-1}=\intop_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^{t}-1}+\intop_{1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^{t}-1} $

Where the latter integral is entire function.

Then, we use lauren expanstion of $ \frac{1}{e^{z}-1} $ in order to continue $ \intop_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^{t}-1} $ in an analytic way.

I calculated the first terms in the Laruent expansion and found that $ \frac{1}{e^{z}-1}=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{12}z-\frac{1}{720}z^{3}+\sum_{k=4}^{\infty}a_{\left(k+1\right)}z^{k} $

So that $$ \intop_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^{t}-1}dt=\intop_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{12}t-\frac{1}{720}t^{3}+\sum_{k=4}^{\infty}a_{\left(k+1\right)}t^{k}\right)t^{s-1}dt $$

$$ =\intop_{0}^{1}\left(t^{s-2}-\frac{1}{2}t^{s-1}+\frac{1}{12}t^{s}-\frac{1}{720}t^{s+2}+\sum_{k=4}^{\infty}a_{k+1}t^{s+k-1}\right) $$

$$ =\frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{12}\frac{1}{s+1}+\sum_{k=4}^{\infty}a_{k+1}\frac{1}{s+k} $$

So that the series we got is an anlytic continuation of the ugly integral, except for the isolated poles

And we get $$ \zeta\left(z\right)\varGamma\left(z\right)=\left[\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{12}\frac{1}{z+1}+\sum_{k=4}^{\infty}a_{k+1}\frac{1}{z+k}+\intop_{1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^{t}-1}\right] $$

So

$$ \zeta\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{\varGamma\left(z\right)}\left[\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{12}\frac{1}{z+1}+\sum_{k=4}^{\infty}a_{k+1}\frac{1}{z+k}+\intop_{1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{z-1}}{e^{t}-1}\right] $$

Has only one simple pole at $z=1$.

My questions are:

1. What gives us the right to exchange the summation and itegral order?
2. How can we say that, for example $ \intop_{0}^{1}t^{s-2}dt=\frac{1}{s-1} $ ?

As I see it, $ \intop_{0}^{1}t^{s-2}dt=\frac{1}{s-1}\left(t^{s-1}\right)_{0}^{1}=\frac{1}{s-1}\left(1^{s-1}-0^{s-1}\right) $

What happens with $ 0^{s-1} $? is it defined for $ s \neq 1 $? what is $0^{-6} $ for example? is it well defined?

Thanks in advance. Clarifications will be very helpful to me. (The exchange of the order of summation and integration really bother me and the author did not explain why it is legit in my analysis book)

Comment: You're actually showing that the equalities hold when $\Re(s)\gt1$, where the exchange in question 1 and the equality in question 2 are easy to verify. But when you're done, you've got a right hand side that's analytic for *all* $s$. That's what gives the analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)$ (and then, since $\Gamma$ has its own analytic continuation with no zeroes and simple poles at the nonpositive integers, you can divide by it to get the final expression for $\zeta$, valid for all $s\not=1$).

Comment: @BarryCipra I see. it clears out why the exchange is legit. If we assume $ Re(s) >1 $, why can we still say that the equality still holds for other regions? I mean, I understand that we got a function which is holomorphic on larger regions, but how come equality still holds?

Comment: The analytic continuation *defines* $\zeta(s)$ in the region to the left of $\Re(s)\gt1$. In effect, the summation formula $\zeta(s)\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ defines $\zeta$ where that formula makes sense (i.e., where the infinite series converges), and the analytic continuation defines it elsewhere.